# GWT opacity of image on canvas

Tags: gwt, canvas

I'm using gwt 2.6.0 and add an image to a canvas like so:

```
Image image = new Image("url"); 
Element element = image.getElement();

canvas.getContext2d().drawImage(ImageElement.as(element), 0, 0);
```

However, I want to set the opacity of the image to 0.5.

If I do the following to the element of the original image:

```
element.getStyle().setOpacity(0.5);
```

and add the image to the page (not the canvas) it works fine, but the image on the canvas is still displayed as normal.

How do I set the opacity of an image on a canvas?

Comment: Did you try `Context2d#setGlobalAlpha(double)`?

Comment: @Baz Using `setGlobalAlpha` worked! Feel free to put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context2d` has a method called `setGlobalAlpha(double)` that should be able to help you.